# Как настроить размер текста в кнопке в python.kivy.MD

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy

Пытаюсь понять как настроить размер текста в кнопке в python.kivy.MD (Кнопка "MDRoundFlatButton"), подскажите, какой нужно вписать аргумент

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй font_size = (число)...